# Connecting to Amazon S3 via Proxy Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, authentication, amazon-s3, proxy

Trying to determine how to pass proxy authentication credentials via Powershell. I'm using the following code, which works for non-proxy connections:

```
$AmazonS3 = [Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($S3AccessKeyID, $S3SecretKeyID)
$S3PutRequest = New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest 
$S3PutRequest.BucketName = $S3BucketName
$S3PutRequest.Key = $S3ObjectKey
$S3Response = $AmazonS3.PutObject($S3PutRequest)
```

The Amazon AWS SDK documentation mentions using the CreateAmazonS3Client object using this method: CreateAmazonS3Client(String, String, AmazonS3Config). AmazonS3Config appears to be an XML file with information containing the proxy settings but I have not discovered the proper syntax for it or where the file should be located.

I would appreciate any suggestions or examples of how to configure this properly to authenticate to a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it's an XML object, just a new S3Config object.

Create a config object:

```
$config = New-Object Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config
$config.ProxyHost = "whatever"
```

Here's some documentation on what to include in the config:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3Config.htm

Then, use that config when creating your connection.

```
$AmazonS3 = [Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($S3AccessKeyID, $S3SecretKeyID, $config)
$S3PutRequest = New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest 
$S3PutRequest.BucketName = $S3BucketName
$S3PutRequest.Key = $S3ObjectKey
$S3Response = $AmazonS3.PutObject($S3PutRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Nodejs AWS SDK you can consider this solution which is similar like above and also mentioned on the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-proxies.html) [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-proxies.html) .

Code for Node.js

```
npm install proxy-agent --save
```

implementation in AWS SDK config object

```
const proxy = require('proxy-agent');

AWS.config.update({
  httpOptions: { agent: proxy('http://internal.proxy.com') }
});
```